# Obtener datos del login con Google en Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, login, google-api

Google actualizó su forma de authenticacion y la librería que estaba utilizando quedó obsoleta.
Mi objetivo es que un usuario inicie sesion con Google y si esa cuenta es válida, envío su mail a un backend que hace ciertas verificaciones.
El problema es que deseo obtener los datos de la cuenta de Google, pero con el nuevo método, no sé como hacerlo.
Me gustaría tener en una constante los datos de su mail y la url de su foto por ejemplo.

Este es lo que tengo importado en el head de mi página:

```
  <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

Y este es mi botón de Google (generado automaticamente con un servicio que tienen ellos).

```
<div id="g_id_onload" data-client_id="ID_DE_CLIENTE"
        data-context="use" data-ux_mode="popup" data-login_uri="" data-auto_prompt="false">
    </div>

    <div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard" data-shape="pill" data-theme="filled_blue" data-text="$ {button.text}"
        data-size="large" data-logo_alignment="left" data-width="300">
    </div>
```

Lo que hace esto es generarme el botón:
[image: Botón de google]

Funciona correctamente la parte de loguearse, pero
**quiero que un usuario ingrese con su cuenta y obtener sus datos**
quisiera saber cómo extraer esa info para posteriormente trabajarla con Typescript.

No logro encontrarlo en la documentación. Gracias!

Continué leyendo y encontré sobre gapi.auth2.BasicProfile que me devuelve lo que necesito, pero aún no sé como importarlo para trabajarlo.

Comment: Has mirado por aqui https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin

Comment: La idea es no usar Firebase :(

Comment: Entonces este enlace https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener los datos usando un el token JWT que genera la implementacion que mencionas, solo nececitas decodificar el JWT token, hay librerias como npm JWT-decode que lo puede hacer